# Malformed SVG asset on Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, svg

For some reason all SVG assets on Android Studio are malformed, whenever I add them to my project on a asset they become crocked or unrecognizable. when I opened old projects this happened as well.

I've tried to check for updates, reinstall the android studio, delete and android folder and nothing have worked.

Did you guys have seen this happened before?

[Malformed asset with the correct clip art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKUr.png)

[Malformed asset with the correct clip art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2LHL.png)

This is the code shown on the Android Studio after a simple clipart import.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:pathData="M15.5 14h-0.79l-0.28-0.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-0.59 4.23-1.57l0.27 0.28v0.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"/></vector>
```

Comment: I don't see any SVGs here.  These just look like the built-in VectorDrawable icons.  Your screenshots appear to show standard Android icons, but then you talk about importing clipart.  So your question is not clear.  Are you using standard Android icons, or are you trying to import your own SVGs?

Comment: Hey Paul
Both actually, at first I though I first was the same thing but by your comment I see they are different. I tried with external SVG right now and they lood odd as well but just some crocked lines not that big as the clipart

Comment: If you are getting weird shapes when rendering standard VectorDrawable icons, then I am not sure what the problem is. Is the window in the background of your screenshots an emulator? Which version of Android is it running? Some early versions of VectorDrawable renderer (in Lollipop) had bugs parsing some path descriptions. If you aren't already, try using the support library VectorDrawable support. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: I have the same issue, but only in Android Studio interface, seems a bug with the preview renderer.